# How to implement Agora Cloud Recording api in flutter?

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I am looking into using the Agora Cloud recording API to record the user's video through the device camera in flutter. The Agora website has the RESTful API calls needed, but I can't figure how to combine that with the camera? How do I have to start the video channel and then call the api?

Comment: To get an answer fast, it is best to ask narrow scope questions. Here is something that helped me https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Agora does provide an on-premise cloud recording solution, so you can easily integrate that to your app. Here is a quickstart guide that you can refer: https://docs.agora.io/en/Recording/recording_api_cpp?platform=Linux

You can also have a look at these sample repositories over here: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Recording/

Comment: Thanks, I have added a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63252956/error-while-calling-the-start-post-call-in-agora-api), please have a look at that.