# Error while calling the start POST call in Agora API

Tags: postman, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am trying to make API calls to the Agora Cloud Recording API through their [Postman Environment](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/6319646/SVSLr9AM?version=latest), but I am getting a 404 error during the query and stop calls. The acquire call returns a 200 response with the ResourceId and the start call also returns a 200 response with the sid.

I have enabled Cloud Recording functions from the Agora dashboard. I have also double-checked my bucket credentials.
This is what the start API body looks like:

```
{
    "cname":"bhavya",
    "uid":"123",
    "clientRequest":{
        "token":"{{token}}",
        "recordingConfig":{
            "maxIdleTime":120,
            "streamTypes":2,
            "audioProfile":1,
            "channelType":1,
            "videoStreamType":0,
            "transcodingConfig":{
                "width":360,
                "height":640,
                "fps":30,
                "bitrate":600,
                "mixedVideoLayout":1,
                "maxResolutionUid":"1"
                }
            },
        "storageConfig":{
            "vendor":{{Vendor}},
            "region":{{Region}},
            "bucket":"{{Bucket}}",
            "accessKey":"{{AccessKey}}",
            "secretKey":"{{SecretKey}}"
        }   
    }
}
```

Moreover, using their [interactive documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/restfulapi/) gives me a 400 bad request error in the start step. This is the error received:

```
{
  "code": 2,
  "reason": "response detail error:2,errMsg:uid inside the List can't be convert to uint32_t!"
}
```

Am I missing some step while setting up the project? What could the solution be?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct method? (get/post)

Comment: @Uuuuuumm yes I think so, the start call is a POST method and query is a GET method

Comment: Take a look at this and see if you have missed out any point: https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/return-404

Comment: @Bhavya, did you enable cloud recording on your project? The cloud recording service is not enabled by default. To enable follow the steps in my Quick Start guide: https://medium.com/agora-io/agora-cloud-recording-quickstart-guide-with-postman-demo-c4a6b824e708

Comment: I found the error, I had included the token field in the start API body but I hadn't initialised token auth in my app. I removed that field and it solved the problem. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

An expired/invalid token will return the response 200 OK for start request but did not start recording. So while querying status or calling stop will throw 404 error as there is no recording is going on.

You must use a valid token while acquiring resource and starting recording and all other request where token is required.

Also don't forget to add authorization token in request header.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for me was the region of the storage cloud (was using Amazon S3).
So here are the main things to solve:

1. Remember the region you set during the `acquire` call. **Forexample** If i set it to `AP` which means Asia Pacific.
2. Create bucket(either AWS S3 or else) that should lie in the same region we used in the acquire call. **For example:** I have used `AP` in the acquire call so my bucket should be like Asia Pacific (Mumbai) **ap-south-1**
3. Now in the storage configurations of the `start` call, the region must be set same as that of the bucket i.e. In my case 14 (AP-SOUTH-1)

Make sure to check the documentation here for the required region:
https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_api_start?platform=RESTful#cloud-storage-configuration